# Does cocos2d framework work on iPad?

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Does Cocos2d iPhone framework work on iPad?

My guess would be yes, but wanted to check if someone has a definitive answer after porting iPhone project with cocos2d to iPad, or starting a new one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cocos2d v0.99.0-rc was released today which formally supports the iPad.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/511

Comment: There is a newer version. Check www.cocos2d-iphone.org for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Apple confirms that all applications available in the app store can be run on iPad
See this link: http://www.apple.com/ipad/app-store/

With that said, Cocos2D is just an opensource library which consists mostly of Objective-c/Cocoa code. It will work just fine.

Also, Apple developer program (link here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone) mentions: "iPhone Developer Program Members can begin developing iPad applications with iPhone SDK 3.2 beta".

Go ahead and get started...

Answer (score -2):

According to Engadget, the iPad runs all iPhone apps with no modifications which means that it supports the Cocos2d library.

[Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2010/01/27/ipad-can-run-all-iphone-apps-unmodified-new-iphone-sdk-out-toda/)

Comment: Sure, but only guaranteed to run at the iPhone resolution. I believe Rudi is trying to establish if Cocos2d works *specifically* with the iPad (at its native resolution).

Comment: iPhone apps will run at the iPhone resolution on the iPad, either partial screen or full screen in pixel doubling mode.

I'm not familiar with the Cocos2d internals but in order to take advantage of the native resolution of the iPad, I'm fairly certain that the Cocos2d library and apps that utilize it will need to be updated to use the new features in the iPhone / iPad SDK.