# Is it cocos2d useful only for iphone?

Tags: ipad-2

I want to build a apps used for ipad 2. Is the cocos2d only available for iphone apps? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does cocos2d framework work on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152530/does-cocos2d-framework-work-on-ipad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.. cocos2d is started with the iPhone (before iPad times) and, Now it supports all version of iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch.. its also available for MAC OS (Cocos2d for OSX) and Android (Cocos2d for Android) ! Its cross-platform version is also available cocos2d-X ! Rock on !

Comment: its going to make the cross-platform gaming easy!